# Python Regular Expression Problems With Multiline Split

Tags: python, regex, string

I have problems splitting multiline matches with re.split in Python. Here's example :

```
str ="""
,,,<?xml version="1.0" 
  encoding="UTF-8"?>,,,

  SOME STRING

-,, Comment 
,,-

    SOME STRING

,,,title,,  ,, svg with dropshadow ,,
title,,,
"""

re.split( r'(,,,.*,,,)|(-,,.*,,-)', str, re.S )
```

This expressions accomplished nothing. Any help?

Comment: What are you actually trying to match?

Comment: where did you get that string from? Seems to be csv. then use csv module.

Comment: Have a look at the [DOTALL flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL)

Comment: @iwin in regex is obvious what I'm trying to match, anything between triple commas or .... another expression group. Dotall is here with re.S.
No csv. I'm making my own parser for specific string format, but everything is matched and splited with inline substrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `str` as a variable name; it clobbers the builtin `str` name.

Use the keyword parameter `flags=re.S` otherwise you are actually setting the positional argument `maxsplit` to `re.S`.

Use non-greedy matching like `(,,,.*?,,,)` so that the `.*` doesn't match your end commas.